# ReactNative: metro bundler is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

We developed with expo and needed an **eject** so We ejected from expo with the option to use expoKit. We heard there are two ways to run the server in this state.

- to build in xcode after `expo start`
- to `react-native run-ios` or`react-native run-android` in another tab after `react-native start`

If We run it the first time, it will work as before, but it doesn't load the **native library** properly. So We ran it the second way, and We get the following error. We think Bundler doesn't map it properly.

[image]

Here is a log of `react-native start` or`react-native start —reset-cache`:

```sh
$ react-native start -- --reset-cache
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native

Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

info Reloading app...
info Opening developer menu...
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * index/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at /Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1088:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/wookee/DEV/JOB/conplus-react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:
```

The following is a log of `react-native run-ios`:

```sh
 react-native run-ios
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - @react-native-community/datetimepicker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/datetimepicker")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-reanimated (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-reanimated")
  - react-native-screens (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-screens")
  - react-native-svg (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-svg")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
error Could not find the following native modules: RNDateTimePicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNSVG. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
info Found Xcode workspace "conplus.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace conplus.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme conplus -destination id=64FD6F9F-6219-4E1B-B544-10D2336715EB")
..............................
info Installing "/Users/wookee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/conplus-dbzfqspmrgwmjehknyymgrazyahg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/conplus.app"
info Launching "com.conlabon.conplus"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
```

The following is a log of `react-native info`:

```sh
react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 187.91 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
```

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "EXPO_DEBUG=true expo eject",
    "lint": "npx eslint .",
    "lint-fix": "npx eslint . --fix",
    "svg": "npx @svgr/cli -d assets/svgjs assets/svg --native",
    "precommit-msg": "echo 'Pre-commits'",
    "build:android": "expo build:android -t app-bundle",
    "build:ios": "expo build:ios"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "precommit-msg",
    "lint"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.0.15",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.1.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
    "delay": "^4.3.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^8.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "immer": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dash": "0.0.11",
    "react-native-element": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-expo-image-cache": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-accessory": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-picker-module": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-svg": "9.13.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.3.1",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.0.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "string-format": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/cli": "^4.3.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-cli": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Even after looking through google and react-native and expo community, I can't figure out how to post a question. If any information I have posted is not enough to infer, I would appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with `Podfile`,`info.plist` or a some command. When using `expo eject`, I chose the option to use`expoKit`. The main reason was that there was no `expoKit` in the project module.

First, install the library as shown below:

```sh
$ yarn add expokit react-native-unimodules
```

Then, after running the bundler server with `expo start`, the code was built with xcode, so both the mobile device and the simulator ran properly.